# Using React within a dynamically loaded es module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have been loading a native ES Module which can be simplified to `src/test.tsx`:

```
export default class Test {
    constructor() {
        console.log('loaded');
    }
}
```

I can load this in my browser and initialize it great, a la:

```
import('http://127.0.0.1:8085/').then(m => { 
  const instance = new m.default();
});
```

However.. if I want to add any external dependency, in this case React, I can't seem to figure out how to target es6 and also bundle React, with tsc. So my dist file contains `import React from 'react';` for which the browser has no idea how to resolve, and produces:

`(index):1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

My tsconfig looks like:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es2015",
        "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
        "declaration": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

Running node v9.5.0, typescript v2.9.2

I have also attempted to use webpack to bundle everything but cannot figure out how to produce a dynamically importable module that way

Comment: why are you trying to import it dynamically in browser?
you can import dynamically in your code and webpack will handle it for you?
want something more?

Answer (score 2):

## The problem

After building your typescript files, at the top of your components you are going to have some import statements like the following (assuming you are targeting es2015)

```
import React from "react";
```

The browser natively does not know how to resolve "react", for that reason it thinks that you have mistaken it for another relative path such as './react.js', and thus the error

```
(index):1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

currently there is a proposal [import-maps](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps) that will enable browsers to natively support theses import statements. Chrome is [experimenting](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5315286962012160) with this, and eventually browser javascript will have to provide a way to resolve imported modules.

## The solution

You can either do a runtime solution or a compile time solution:

### Runtime solution

I'm gonna use [systemjs](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) since it is already supported by typescript out of the box, you wanna change `"module"` to "system" inside `compilerOptions`, like

```
 "compilerOptions": {
   ....
   "module":"system"
  }
```

This will make typescript compile to a systemjs compatible code, in your root index html file you wanna include the systemjs file, and u also have to tell systemjs where to look for these modules

```
// root index.html
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@6.3.2/dist/system.js"></script>
 <script type="systemjs-importmap">
      {
        // for each library you add u have to include it here
        // documentation is here [systemjs import maps][3]d
        "imports": {
          "react": "https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js",
          "react-dom": "https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"
        }
      }
  </script>
```

and later you can dynamically load the needed module

```
// load your module later
System.import("./dist/index.js").catch()
```

### compile time solution

You can use webpack, parcel or any other javascript bundler that will resolve these modules for you at compile time, and give you a bundle that has these modules already bundled within it.

I recommend a compile time solution, as it provides you with much more than just resolving modules, you can use css preprocessors, css modules, base64 inline images, and many things more.